# Update single element of the array in redux state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux

I have a redux state that contains an array of objects, for each of these object I call an api to get more data

```
objects.forEach((obj, index) => {
    let newObj = { ...obj };
        service.getMoreData()
            .then(result => {
                newObj.data = result;

                let newObjects =  [...this.props.objectsList] ;

                let index = newObjects.findIndex(el => el.id === newObj.id);
                if (index != -1) {
                    newObjects[index] = newObj;
                    this.props.updateMyState({ objectsList: newObjects });
                }
            })
```

When I get two very close responses the state is not updated correctly, I lose the data of the first response.

What is the right way to update a single element of the array? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So since i don't know what `service` is and there isn't that much here to go off, here is what I would do from my understanding of what it looks like your doing:

So first let's set up a reducer to handle the part of redux state that you want to modify:

```js
// going to give the reducer a default state
// array just because I don't know
// the full use case 

// you have an id in your example so this is the best I can do :(
const defaultState = [{ id: 123456 }, { id: 123457 }];

const someReducer = (state=defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    // this is the main thing we're gonna use
    case 'UPDATE_REDUX_ARRAY':
      return [
        ...action.data
      ]

    // return a default state == the state argument
    default:
      return [ 
        ...state 
      ]
  }
}

export default someReducer;
```

Next you should set up some actions for the reducer, this is optional and you can do it all inline in your component but I'd personally do it this way:

```js
// pass data to the reducer using an action
const updateReduxArray = data => {
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_REDUX_ARRAY',
    data: data
  }
}

// export like this because there might
// be more actions to add later 
export {
  updateReduxArray
}
```

Then use the reducer and action with React to update / render or whatever else you want

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { updateReduxArray } from 'path_to_actions_file';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { axios } from 'axios';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const SomeComponent = () => {

  // set up redux dispatch
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // get your redux state
  const reduxArray = useSelector(state => state.reduxArray)  // your gonna have to name this however your's is named

  // somewhere to store your objects (state)
  const [arrayOfObjects, updateArrayOfObjects] = useState([]); 

  // function to get data from your API
  const getData = async () => {
    // I'm using axios for HTTP requests as its pretty
    // easy to use 

    // if you use map you can just return the value of all API calls at once
    const updatedData = await Promise.all(reduxArray.map(async (object, index) => {
      // make the api call
      const response = axios.get(`https://some_api_endpoint/${object.id}`)
        .then(r => r.data)

      // return the original object with the addition of the new data
      return {
        ...response,
        ...object
      }
    }))

    // once all API calls are done update the state
    // you could just update redux here but this is
    // a clean way of doing it incase you wanna update 
    // the redux state more than once
    // costs more memory to do this though
    updateArrayOfObjects(updatedData)
  }

  // basicity the same as component did mount 
  // if you're using classes
  useEffect(() => {
    // get some data from the api
    getData()
  }, [ ])


  // every time arrayOfObjects is updated
  // also update redux
  useEffect(() => {
    // dispatch your action to the reducer
    dispatch(updateReduxArray(arrayOfObjects))
  }, [arrayOfObjects])


  // render something to the page??
  return (
    <div>
      { reduxArray.length > 0
        ? reduxArray.map(object => <p>I am { object.id }</p>)
        : <p>nothing to see here</p>
      }
    </div>
  )
} 

export default SomeComponent;
```

You could also do this so that you only update one object in redux at a time but even then you'd still be better off just passing the whole array to redux so I'd do the math on the component side rather than the reducer .

Note that in the component I used react state and `useEffect`. You might not need to do this, you could just handle it all in one place when the component mounts but we're using React so I just showcased it incase you want to use it somewhere else :)

Also lastly I'm using `react-redux` here so if you don't have that set up (you should do) please go away and do that first, adding your `Provider` to the root component. There are plenty of guides on this.

Comment: I don't want to update the array at once, but I would like to update the individual items in the array as the responses from the API come in